# Subfields of the finite field: Is divisibility of multiplication groups a sufficient condition?

Tags: divisibility, finite-fields

For instance, $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ does not contain a (copy of) $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, because of divisibility: multiplication groups have $ 7 $, resp. $3$ elements and $ 3\nmid 7 $

But is true that if $(p^k-1) | (p^n -1) $ ($ p $ prime, $ n>k $ integer), then  $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ contains a copy of  $\mathbb{Z}_p^k$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2^3$ is not a field. However, there is a field $\Bbb F_8$ of order $8$, whose additive group is isomoprhic to $\Bbb Z_2^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p^k$ roots of $X^{p^k}-X$ form a subfield in that case.